# Airflow and Google Sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets, airflow

I'm new to Airflow and Python. I'm trying to connect Airflow with Google Sheets and although I have no problem connecting with Python, I do not know how I could do it from Airflow.

I have searched for information everywhere but I only find Python information with gspread or with BigQuery, but not with Google Sheets.

I would appreciate any advice or link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no gsheet hook or operator in airflow at the moment. If security is not a concern you could publish it to the web and pull it in airflow using the SimpleHttpOperator.

If security is a concern I recommend going the PythonOperator route and use `df2gspread` library. Airflow version >= 1.9 can help obtaining credentials for df2gspread

Comment: OK thanks.

I have two options:
1.- Develop the hook / operators
2.- Connect with other systems and let Airflow call those processes.

I think I'll choose the second one.